# Automating a Daily Picture Blog?

Tags: images, uploads, automation

I was wondering if anyone could give me some suggestions on how best I could streamline the following;

I have a WordPress blog (privately hosted) which I update daily (well, I normally schedule a load of updates at once) with pictures which I upload, tag and write a very brief comment on.

I was originally considering a folder on the server I could FTP images into and then I would write something that would look there daily and create a post based on the picture, but then I wasn't sure about the meta data that I want along with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S I would make this a community wiki (as I am not sure there is even one answer let alone one stand out correct answer!) but I don't have enough the right privileges yet!

Comment: **Please keep in mind that there are personal image hosting platforms starting and dying each day and that answers to this question should not rely on a specific third party service.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are **lots of ways to accomplish a daily picture blog** so I'll just give you how I'd approach it.

If I wanted to set up a photoblog on WordPress I'd start with a [**Flickr**](http://www.flickr.com) account and leverage it *(or if you don't like Flickr for some reason you can also look at [PhotoBucket](http://photobucket.com/), [SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com/), [Picasa](http://picasaweb.google.com/) or [one](http://www.inquisitr.com/1095/6-alternatives-to-flickr-now-yahoo-is-in-full-control/) of the [other](http://www.fluther.com/5846/which-is-the-best-flickr-alternative/) Flickr [alternatives](http://www.photographybay.com/2007/12/03/flickr-alternatives/).)*

### Using Flickr

With Flickr there [**are**](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/12/flickr-uploading-alternatives-for-the-discerning-iphoto-user.ars) [**bulk**](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/10-tools-to-upload-images-to-flickr-with-ease/) [**uploading**](http://www.labnol.org/internet/pictures/batch-upload-photographs-to-flickr/1825/) [**tools**](http://www.flickr.com/tools/) to make it easy for your to upload lots of photos including [**lots of tools for managing a large number of photos**](http://pulse2.com/2010/07/20/list-of-80-flickr-tools-and-games-used-for-pictures-management-sharing-etc/).

Flickr itself has [**built-in tools to support photo-blogging**](http://www.flickr.com/help/blogging/) including [**email-to-blog**](http://www.flickr.com/account/uploadbyemail/).

And if the existing tools don't give you enough control with Flickr **you can always write some PHP scripts to integrate and automate**. There are lots of blog posts to show you how *(and I'll show you how to write one as well, below):*

- [**Search for photos using PHP and the flickr API**](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/search-for-photos-using-php-and-the-flickr-api/)
- [**Flickr API Fun**](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/34-Flickr-API-Fun.html)
- [**Serialized PHP Response Format**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.php.html)
- [**How to Create a Photo Gallery using the Flickr API**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-create-a-photo-gallery-using-the-flickr-api/)
- [**Integrating Flickr Photo Streams with PHP**](http://devzone.zend.com/article/11775)
- [**5 Lessons in Getting Started with the Flickr API and PHP**](http://wynia.org/wordpress/2005/12/5-lessons-in-getting-started-with-the-flickr-api-and-php)

And at least a few PHP libraries to simplify access to the Flickr API:

- [**phpFlickr**](http://phpflickr.com/2010/05/13/phpflickr-3-0-released/)
- [**Laughing Meme Flickr API Library for PHP**](http://laughingmeme.org/2008/12/11/my-flickr-api-library-for-php/)

### Exploring the Flickr API

So let's say you want to do a little simple photo blogging to WordPress using files that have been uploaded to Flickr? The first step is to **get an API Key**:

- [**The Flickr App Garden - Create an App**](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/)

While you are at it you might want to just scan the API docs:

- [**Flickr API Documentation**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)

Now there are a bunch of different ways to query Flickr via their API. I'll show how by [**Querying a Photo Set**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html) but you could also consider [**Searching by Tags**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html).

For the first example I'll use my Flickr photo set entitled *"[Barber Motorcycle Museum - Oct 21-22 2006](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mikeschinkel/sets/72157594340403773/)" (I'm using it because people seem to like it; it gets lots of traffic.)* You'll need to get the `photoset_id` which you can find in the URL:

[image: Where to find 'photoset_id' on a Flickr Photo Setlink text]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101013-153049.png))</sub>

Next you need to call the `flickr.photosets.getPhotos` method of the Flickr API with a URL of the following format:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key={YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE}&photoset_id=72157594340403773&media=photos&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
```

**Note** that once you replace `{YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE}` with your own API key you can actually call it from your browser and it will look something like this:

[image: Calling the Flickr API directly from your Browser]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101013-154814.png))</sub>

Also note that I request [**JSON**](http://json.org/) back using the `format=json&nojsoncallback=1` URL parameters because I find it much easier to handle JSON than XML, and the `nojsoncallback` omits the callback on would need if working in Javascript.

What you'll get back is **a nested data structure containing a list of photos**, and for each photos you'll get an object with the following attributes *(what I'm showing below it the output of the first element of the array of photos as generated by the standard PHP `print_r()` function):*

```
[0] => stdClass Object
  (
    [id] => 276672853
    [secret] => 099eaa1af2
    [server] => 107
    [farm] => 1
    [title] => Barber Motorcycle Museum - Oct 22 2006 (500)
    [isprimary] => 0
  )
```

### Flickr's Photo URL Formats

Now that we have our list of recent photos you next need to **understand Flickr's Photo URL format** which you can read more about here:

- [**Flickr's Photo Source URLs**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html)

In general Flickr's photo URLs go like this:

#### 500px Wide or High "Standard" Photo:

- `http://farm{farm-id}.static.flickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg`

This version will be 500 pixels on its longest side.

#### The Original Image:

- `http://farm{farm-id}.static.flickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{o-secret}_o.(jpg|gif|png)`

This can be whatever was uploaded, a .JPG, a .GIF or a .PNG.

#### Specific Sized Versions:

These are always .JPG:

- `http://farm{farm-id}.static.flickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}_[size].jpg`

Where `[size]` is one of:

- **s** - small square 75x75
- **t** - thumbnail, 100 on its longest side
- **m** - small, 240 on its longest side
- **z** - medium, 640 on its longest side
- **b** - large, 1024 on its longest side (only exists for very large original images)

So the following URL taken from the example results returned above pulls the photo that follows *(note how the `z` before the `.jpg` indicates a photo 640 pixels wide on the longest size:)*

- https://farm1.static.flickr.com/107/276672853_099eaa1af2_z.jpg

[image: Photo of Motorcycle on Flickr]

Armed with all of the above information we can now create a PHP script using WordPress' `WP_Http` class to retrieve the photos from our set. I wrote a simple script which you can copy into the root of your website being sure to replace with your own `api_key` and `photoset_id` before running it:

```
include "wp-load.php";
define('FLICKR_API_KEY','{YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE}');
define('FLICKR_GET_URL','http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/');
define('PHOTO_SIZE_CHAR', 's'); // s = 75x75 pixels on longest side
$result = flickr_get(array(
  'method'      => 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
  'photoset_id' => '{YOUR_PHOTOSET_ID_GOES_HERE}',
  'media'       => 'photos'
));
if (isset($result['body']->photoset->photo)) {
  $size = PHOTO_SIZE_CHAR;
  foreach($result['body']->photoset->photo as $photo) {
    extract((array)$photo);
    $url = "http://farm{$farm}.static.flickr.com/{$server}/{$id}_{$secret}_{$size}.jpg";
    echo "<img src=\"{$url}\" alt=\"{$title}\" />\n";
  }
}
function flickr_get($params,$args=array()) {
  $http = new WP_Http();
  $params['api_key'] = FLICKR_API_KEY;
  $params['format'] = 'json';
  $params['nojsoncallback'] = 1;
  $params = http_build_query($params);
  $url = FLICKR_GET_URL . "?{$params}";
  $result = $http->get($url,$args);
  if (isset($result['response']['code']) && $result['response']['code'] == 200)
    $result['body'] = json_decode($result['body']);
  else
    $result = false;
  return $result;
}
```

Using the above with my API key and my Photoset ID I get the following:

[image: Output of a PHP Script Showing a Flickr Photoset]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/http__wp30.dev_test_test27.php%3FXDEBUG_SESSION_START%3DWebIDE1-20101013-162722.png))</sub>

### PHP Script for Posting of a Flickr Photoset Photo to your Blog

Based on all that I've written a page called `blog-from-flickr.php` that you can put in the root of your website and call to get the following simple form:

[image: Blog From Flickr PHP Script for WordPress]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101014-015058.png))</sub>

Enter a valid Photoset ID and then click that button and you'll get be redirected to a blog post that looks something like this!

[image: Blog Post Generated from a Flickr Photoset Photo via a PHP Script]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101013-182903.png))</sub>

To get it all working was a bit more involved than the simple code above and more than I have time left to fully document but I'll post it below for your review (and you can also [**download it from here**](http://gist.github.com/625088)).

Of special note are the following aspects in the code:

- The script **pulls the twenty five (25) most recent photos** from the photoset and blog the earliest one of those. I assumed you'd want to upload in bulk and then post chronologically. If you upload more than 25 then you need to change the value of the constant `FLICKR_PHOTO_COUNT` to something larger, up to 500 *(500 is the limit specified by Flickr.)* Increasing it will only slightly increase how long it takes the script to run; it might not even be noticeable.
- The script **stores Flickr's photo ID as a hidden custom field in `wp_postmeta`** using the key `'_flickr_photo_id'`. That's how I can tell if it's been blogged before or not.
- The script **uses an HTTP `POST` method** *(i.e. using an HTML `<form>`)* vs an **HTTP `GET` method** *(calling a URL directly)* to **avoid accidentally triggering the posting process** and to **allow posting from a different Photoset**.
- The script uses `current_user_can('publish_posts')` to **ensure only a logged-in user** with posting rights can trigger the posting logic.
- The script grabs **the photo's *description*** from Flickr and use it **as a prefix to the `<img>` tag for the post content** *(note my example screenshot didn't have a description hence you see only the photo.)*
- The script **calls PHP's `getimagesize()` with a URL** of the photo to get the height and width for the `<img>` tag; if your server is not configured for that you won't get size and width tags on your images *(actually the code might crash; mine works so I couldn't test. If it crashes, you'll know. :)*
- I didn't go to the effort to bring the tags over from Flickr and add them as tags, but that would be a worthwhile exercise for someone else.

And that's about it. On to the code...

#### The Flickr Photo Blogging Code:

```
<?php
/*

  blog-from-flickr.php

  Allows the WordPress blog owner to blog a recent photo from a Flickr Photoset just by clicking a button.

  Author: Mike Schinkel (http://mikeschinkel.com)

  Just drop this example into the root of your website and call directly to see it work.
  Use the class in your plugins or themes.

  In Answer To: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2830/

*/

include "wp-load.php";
define('FLICKR_API_KEY','{YOUR_FLICKR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE}');
define('DEFAULT_PHOTOSET_ID','{YOUR DEFAULT_PHOTOSET_GOES_HERE');
define('FLICKR_PHOTO_COUNT',25);

define('FLICKR_GET_URL','http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/');

$photoset_id = DEFAULT_PHOTOSET_ID;

if (count($_POST)==0)
  echo <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    Enter Flickr Photoset ID: <input type="text" name="photoset_id" value="{$photoset_id}" size="25" />
    &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Blog Recent Photo from Flickr!" />
    <input type="hidden" name="go" value="go!" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
else
  BlogFlickrPhotoSetPhoto::blog_photoset_photo($_POST['photoset_id']);

class BlogFlickrPhotoSetPhoto {
  static function blog_photoset_photo($photoset_id) {
    if (current_user_can('publish_posts')) {
      $photoset = self::get_photoset_photos($photoset_id);
      if (!$photoset) {
        echo 'Not a valid Photoset ID. <a href="#">Try again</a>.';
      } else {
        $photo = self::get_photo_to_blog($photoset);
        if (!$photo) {
          echo 'Unexpected Error. Photo Retrieval Failed.';
        } else {
          $permalink = self::blog_photo($photo);
          wp_safe_redirect($permalink);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  static function blog_photo($photo) {
    $img = self::get_photo_html($photo);
    $photo_info = self::get_photo_info($photo->id);
    $description = ($photo_info ? "{$photo_info['body']->photo->description->_content}<br/>" : '');
    $url = self::get_photo_url($photo);
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
      'post_title' => $photo->title,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_author' => 1,
      'post_content' => "{$description}{$img}",
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'comment_status' => 'open',
      'ping_status' => 'open',
      'post_parent' => 0,
    ));
    if ($post_id) {
      update_post_meta($post_id,'_flickr_photo_id',$photo->id);
      $url = get_permalink($post_id);
    } else {
    $url = false;
    }
    return $url;
  }
  static function get_photo_to_blog($photoset) {
    global $wpdb;
    $photo = false;
    if (isset($photoset['body']->photoset->photo)) {

      //Collect the list of Flickr Photo_ids from our "N" most resent photoset photos
      $photos = $photoset['body']->photoset->photo;
      foreach($photos as $index => $photo) {
        $photo_ids[$index] = $photo->id;
      }
      $photo_id_list = "'" . implode("','",$photo_ids) . "'";

      //Get a list of all photos we've already blogged
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_flickr_photo_id' && meta_value IN ({$photo_id_list})");

      //Remove any photos from the list we've already blogged
      $photo_ids = array_flip($photo_ids);
      foreach($posts as $post) {
        if (isset($photo_ids[$post->meta_value])) {
          unset($photo_ids[$post->meta_value]);
        }
      }

      //Grab the earliest photo we've not blogged
      if (count($photo_ids)==0) {
        $photo = false;
      } else {
        krsort($photo_ids);
        $photo = $photos[reset($photo_ids)];
      }
    }
    return $photo;
  }
  static function get_photoset_photos($photoset_id) {
    $photoset = self::flickr_get(array(
      'method'      => 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
      'photoset_id' => $photoset_id,
      'media'       => 'photos',
      'per_page'    => FLICKR_PHOTO_COUNT,
    ));
    return $photoset;
  }
  static function get_photo_info($photo_id) {
    $photo_info = self::flickr_get(array(
      'method'   => 'flickr.photos.getInfo',
      'photo_id' => $photo_id,
    ));
    return $photo_info;
  }
  static function get_photo_html($photo,$size='') {
    $url = self::get_photo_url($photo,$size);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($url);
    $hwstring = image_hwstring($width, $height);
    return "<img src=\"{$url}\" alt=\"{$title}\" {$hwstring} />\n";
  }
  static function get_photo_url($photo,$size='') {
    extract((array)$photo);
    $size = (!empty($size) ? "_{$size}" : ''); // If empty the 500px version will be returned.
    return "http://farm{$farm}.static.flickr.com/{$server}/{$id}_{$secret}{$size}.jpg";
  }
  static function flickr_get($params,$args=array()) {
    $http = new WP_Http();
    $params['api_key'] = FLICKR_API_KEY;
    $params['format'] = 'json';
    $params['nojsoncallback'] = 1;
    $params = http_build_query($params);
    $url = FLICKR_GET_URL . "?{$params}";
    $result = $http->get($url,$args);
    if (isset($result['response']['code']) && $result['response']['code'] == 200)
      $result['body'] = json_decode($result['body']);
    else
      $result = false;
    return $result;
  }
}
```

### Fully Automatic Flickr Photo Blogging

If you need to go even farther, you can recode the above to use a pseudo-cron instead of triggering on an HTTP `POST`. Here's a link to a few articles that can help with that:

- [**Timing is everything: scheduling in WordPress**](http://blog.slaven.net.au/archives/2007/02/01/timing-is-everything-scheduling-in-wordpress/)
- [**Pseudo Cron Jobs with WordPress**](http://chipsandtv.com/articles/wordpress-pseudo-crons)
- [**Experiments with WP Cron**](http://www.simonwheatley.co.uk/2009/03/04/experiments-with-wp-cron/)
- [**Cron Developers Demo Plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cron-demo/)

And if pseudo-cron isn't good enough, you can alway rename the script to an obscure name and use real cron to retrieve that obscurely-named URL. If you need to go that route, [**check Google to learn how to set up a cron task.**](http://www.google.com/search?q=setting+up+a+cron+task).

In either case with cron you'll probably have to remove the `current_user_can()` code because you won't be logged in.

#### P.S. Getting your Flickr NSID *(User ID)*

Beyond the above you may find you need to **get your Flickr NSID** *(aka your user ID)* for some of the methods, you can find it here:

- [**flickr.people.getInfo**](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/?method=flickr.people.getInfo)

#### P.P.S. Authenticating a PHP Script with Flickr is Harder

You may note that none of my examples used required the caller to be authenticated. It's a good bit more involved to authenticate so if you need that be sure to look into the Flickr PHP libraries mentioned as I think they handle that.

Comment: Flickr is def the way to go.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you, and thanks for the insanely complete answer.

Comment: *@Toby* - You are welcome. I enjoyed writing it. Hope it comes in handy.

Comment: *@MikeSchinkel* You're really gunning for an induction into the "Stellar StackExchange Hall of Fame" aren't you?

Comment: *@EAMann* Nah, just don't know when to shut up. ;-)

Comment: Holy smoke!! Awesome work man. Thanks for writing such a detailed answer.

Comment: @skillguru! You're welcome. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

I would actually recommend using the built-in post by email functionality instead.  You set up a private email address (`mysupersecretaddress12345@mydomain.com`) and send both the images and your descriptions to that address.  WordPress will then create a new post from your email and automatically attach the image.

This is a bit easier than FTP.

Comment: This is a great option. And considering you can take a picture with your smart phone and e-mail that way as well, you could easily "automate" things for quick posts easily.

Comment: *@EAMann* - Sorry to piggyback this answer's comments but really glad to see your new avatar. I so much enjoy being able to *"see"* who I'm writing to as we humans are hardwired for recognizing *faces* *(I like this guy's take: http://hivelogic.com/articles/why-your-avatar-matters)*. I think I get grumpy interacting with those whose face I can't see. Now I'm just hoping our other two most active non-facers (*@Rarst* and *@NetConstructor*) will follow: http://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101014-193647.png

Comment: *@MikeSchinkel* My previous avatar was a stylized version of an old photo of me a friend took ... I created it before the Gravatar service was widely used and just stuck with it when everything changed over.  But it's been a few years since the last photo was taken and I wanted an update.  Besides, a B&W sketch of a silhouette isn't as useful as an actual photo. :)

Comment: *@EAMann* - Yeah, I think stylized avatars are great in the right contexts, but in generally I really appreciate when I can see the face of the person I'm interacting with. I really think it helps build better relationships. I think that's one thing mailing lists really lack. And as much at Jeff and Joel say SE is about answers, I don't think those of us doing lots of answering would get as much value out of our effort without the relationships and (non-point based) reputations we can build. FWIW.

Comment: built-in post by email functionality in wordpress. Learning so much new stuff today. Thought only posterous does that.

Comment: The core team is actually in the process of extracting post-by-email into a plug-in ... so eventually it'll be an optional value add rather than an unknown built-in feature :)